# TurnKey FileServer Appliance - SAMBA Shares configuration

Tags: samba, turnkey-linux

Now, it is my first time with Linux and a SAMBA File server. I am using the TurnKey Linux File Server Appliance.

I have installed it native on my new fileserver machine (an OLD Dell 670 Workstation 2GB RAM and 2TB x 4 SATA)
I can access webshell, webmin, extplorer - all good, but :

My Scenario is, that I want to have the following Groups of users, namely (HR, EXEC, IT, Marketing, Sales, Production) ... I will then create users individually and add them to there respective groups.

for a test, i created a HR group and add our HR person to it, they can see the share listed when they connect from a windows machine but they can't create anything inside it.

I clicked on the option "synchronize UNIX user and samba user" and synchronize UNIX group and samba group as well.

Also, I have active directory, what is the real benefit of binding my file server to our Active Directory and how reliable is that ?

I will have a few more questions which I will post once I have tried and failed,

will be grateful for your assistance on the above
Kind Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Binding your file server to AD means that you don't have to independently manage two user directories and authentication sources. It means that AD will serve as The One True Source™ for all that information. It means users who want to keep the file server password and their other password (AD) in sync won't have to change it twice via different interfaces to do it.

I can't speak to the reliability of winbind (the component necessary to "bind" your Linux file server to AD) but I know that it's been used for many, many years and it very well should be reliable by now. See the [SambaWiki for more information on winbind and AD](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Samba_&_Active_Directory).

As for access to the shares, what are the share permissions set to in `smb.conf`? I'm not familiar with the TurnKey appliance but presumably there is an interface (webmin?) that manages the Samba shares? Can you show us what the share definitions look like from that interface? If not, can you post the relevant section of `smb.conf`?

Comment: Thanks rthomson for your detailed response, just one more quick question - what permissions I Should assign to a group that can ONLY list, download and ADD to the Folder (Samba Share) but the can't delete it, the 2nd User will be Full ADMIN of the share. Will be grateful. Kind Regards

Comment: Under your share definition, you can list admin users with the `admin users = <username>` directive. However, I haven't looked into how to allow file creation while simultaneous disallowing modifying or deleting files for other non-admin users.